# append previous line with current line if the file contains blanks

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I want to append lines to the previous line if the blank line is followed by the line.

**For example:**

```
A
B
C
1
D
E
B
```

**Ouput:**

```
A
B
C
1D
EB
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try this: `perl -0777 -pE 's/\n\n+//g' file`

Comment: if `awk`, `awk '$0==""{flag=0;next}{if(!flag){flag=1;printf "%s", $0}else{printf "\n%s", $0}}END{printf "\n"}' file`. If a line is empty, don't print the next line on a newline, that's what this `awk` script does.

Answer (score 3):

See also Håkon Hægland's comment above. This is one of those problems that lends itself to treating the whole file as one long string (with embedded newline characters). Perl has a flag `-0` for changing or turning off the default "record separator" definition that accomplishes this. Then you just need to realize that, depending on your definition of "blank line", you seem to be requesting that all sequences of **two or more** newline characters in a row simply be removed. (If your definition of "blank line" can include lines with blank characters on them (whitespace, i.e. spaces and tabs), you'll need a more complicated expression.) This compact one-liner will do it:

```
$ perl -0pe 's/\n\n+//g' blanklines
A
B
C
1D
EB
```

Now please tell me this was not a homework assignment.

Update: I realized a couple of additional things. 1) Since newline is included in Perl's whitespace special escape `\s`, expanding to handle the case of blank lines having blank characters on them is **not** really more complex: `perl -0pe 's/\n\s+//g' blanklines`. 2) There is an edge case that this solution doesn't handle right: blank lines at the end of the input. I'll leave that as a problem for the student. :-)

Comment: What if the line breaks are CRLF? Or mixed?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, use the `\s` solution in the update but change the `\n` to `[\n\r]`.

Comment: That is a wrong approach.

Comment: Agreed, the "right" approach would be to 1) detect if there is any CRLF, 2) determine which is the dominant style if there is any mixing, 3) change all CRLF to LF, 4) do the perl, 5) change all LF to CRLF if CRLF was the dominant style. But this is all beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @JeffY : How would we identified for CRLF characters ?